# web_reg_save_param_regexp loadrunner- values not getting extracted

Tags: loadrunner

I am using web_reg_save_param_regexp() function to extract some data from the response, but i am getting null on the input

**Text i am trying to extract:**
submit.com?method=data&id=123456789&pid=12121212&mid=7766454&seqnum=111111&

Objective is to extract first three id's in the text

**I tried the function as:**
web_reg_save_param_regexp("ParamName=id",
"RegExp=id=(.*?)&(.*?)pid=(.*?)&(.*?)mid=(.*?)&(.*?)SeqNum=(.*?)",
"Ordinal=1",``
SEARCH_FILTERS,
LAST);

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your regular expression doesn't match the response text
I would try something like this:
`RegExp=id=(.*)&pid=(.*)&mid=(.*)&seqnum=(.*)&`

Comment: Still i am seeing my response as null:  The text  is as of below : <<id=1111111&amp;pid=1212121&amp;mid=222222&amp;seqnum=12121233&amp;>>    I want to capture | ID, PID,MID from the text string. i tried the above and not working

Comment: I think you will need to debug it. Try separating it to a regular expression per filed and not capture all the fields in one expression

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`(?<=id=)(.+?)(?=&)`

Answer (score 0):

Add the group value as `3` in the function after the regular expression line and before the ordinal line, so that it will take the first three things like `id=(.?)&(.?)pid=(.?)&(.?)mid=(.?)&(.?)` and give the result.